# How to add a picture to android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, alert

Documentation says something like this:

> If you want to display a more complex view, look up the FrameLayout
>   called "custom" and add your view to it:
>
> ```
> FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.custom);
>  fl.addView(myView, new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
> ```

My code looks like this:

```
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

ImageView myView = new ImageView(mContext);
myView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);

FrameLayout f1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.custom);
f1.addView(myView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

alert.show();
```

f1 gets always null, and thus get NullPointerException.

If I change the code like below, it does not help:

```
FrameLayout f1 = (FrameLayout) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.custom);
```

There is a similar question on the site about an inflator for a custom layout, but this is a different case.

Comment: Can you tell what do you exactly want, do you have any image that could illustrate the extact UI that you want

Comment: I just want to use the documented way to add a view to an alert dialog layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add    `setView (View view, int viewSpacingLeft, int viewSpacingTop, int viewSpacingRight, int viewSpacingBottom)`

```
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = alertDialogBuilder
            .setTitle("title")
            .setView(fl,24,24,24,24)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }
                    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder .create();
    alertDialog.show();
```